# IE6 - IE8 javascript error... help?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bookmarklet

I'm making a bookmarklet to view cookies for any site, it works in every browser from IE9+, firefox, chrome, safari, etc. I don't care about IE5.5, so the main issue is the javascript error on IE6 - IE8. They error saying "Unterminated string constant" from the following:

```
javascript:if(document.getElementById('cookieelement')!=null){
  document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('cookieelement'));
} else {
  document.body.innerHTML='<div style="font-size:10pt;color:#000000;padding:10px;border:solid 1px #000000;background:white;display:block;position:fixed;top:0px;z-index:999999999999;" id="cookieelement"></div>'+document.body.innerHTML;
  cookieelement=document.getElementById('cookieelement');
  cookies=document.cookie.split(';');
  cookiehtml=('<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:Solid 1px #000000;">\n');
  for(i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){
    cookie=cookies[i];
    name=cookie.substr(0,cookie.indexOf('='),cookie.length);
    val=cookie.substr(cookie.indexOf('=')+1,cookie.length);
    cookiehtml+=('\t<tr>\n\t\t<td style="padding:3px;text-align:right;padding-right:10px;border:Solid 1px #000000;">'+name+'</td>\n\t\t<td style="padding:3px;text-align:left;border:Solid 1px #000000;">'+val+'</td>\n\t</tr>\n');
  }
  cookiehtml+=('</table>');cookieelement.innerHTML=cookiehtml;
}
void(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not get a *unterminated string content* error in IE7. 
However, I got an equally cryptic *object does not support property or method* message.

This could be because in IE it is possible to access elements by their `id` globally. Meaning if you have a element with id `abcd`, you can access it via `document.abcd` globally. this is not standard, but possible in IE.

Try changing the name of your cookie element variable to something else. I changed it to `cookieElement1`, and voila, it works:

```
javascript: if(document.getElementById('cookieelement')!=null){   document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('cookieelement')); } else {   document.body.innerHTML='<div style="font-size:10pt;color:#000000;padding:10px;border:solid 1px #000000;background:white;display:block;position:fixed;top:0px;z-index:999999999999;" id="cookieelement"></div>'+document.body.innerHTML;   cookieelement1=document.getElementById('cookieelement');   cookies=document.cookie.split(';');   cookiehtml=('<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:Solid 1px #000000;">\n');   for(i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){     cookie=cookies[i];     name=cookie.substr(0,cookie.indexOf('='),cookie.length);     val=cookie.substr(cookie.indexOf('=')+1,cookie.length);     cookiehtml+=('\t<tr>\n\t\t<td style="padding:3px;text-align:right;padding-right:10px;border:Solid 1px #000000;">'+name+'</td>\n\t\t<td style="padding:3px;text-align:left;border:Solid 1px #000000;">'+val+'</td>\n\t</tr>\n');   }   cookiehtml+=('</table>');cookieelement1.innerHTML=cookiehtml; } void(0);
```